# Use SAML Single Sign-On to obtain OAuth access token or code for using Box.com API

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, saml, box-api

We have SAML-based single sign-on (SSO) enabled between our company's Intranet Portal and Box so that the users do not use username and passwords to login to Box.com. They just click on a button on Intranet Portal which posts a SAML assertion to Box.com to authenticate.

We would like to provide the ability to our users to search their Box documents directly from the Intranet Portal and the Box.com API looks like a perfect fit. However, it requires OAuth access token.

The question is:

1. Is there any way to obtain the OAuth token from SAML assertion?
2. The Box Embed allows embedding of folders view on to other sites. Is there any way to embed just the search results. In other words, I am looking for a way to do this `<iframe src="https://www.box.com/....?search=keywords"></iframe>` where it would just display the search results in iframe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1.** I don't know if it is possible to get an OAuth2 token from a SAML assertion -- I'd think that it isn't -- but you can pretty easily configure a Box application to support your company's SSO. The [first step of Box's OAuth2 authorization](http://developers.box.com/oauth/) process is to redirect the user's browser to a URL similar to:

```
https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID
```

On this page the user can log into Box with whatever credentials they chose and authorize your application to touch their files. In order to take advantage of your company's SSO integration, you will instead redirect the user to:

```
https://sso.services.box.net/sp/startSSO.ping
     ?PartnerIdpId=<YOUR_IDP_URN>
     &TargetResource=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.box.com%2Fapi%2Foauth2%2Fauthorize%3Fresponse_type%3Dcode%26client_id%3DMY_CLIENT_ID
```

Where:

- The `PartnerIdpId` is the URN of your company's IdP.
- The `TargetResource` is the HTTP-encoded version of the default OAuth2 authorization URL that was described above.

This will tell Box to bounce the user over to your IdP for authorization instead of prompting the user to log in with Box credentials. The OAuth2 process will then carry on as normal.

**2.** I don't know that this is possible either, but with a valid OAuth2 token you can easily tap into the Box [Search](http://developers.box.com/docs/#search) API.

Comment: Thank a lot for your suggestion! I will give it a try. I had tried pre-logging in the user (by posting SAML assertion to Box in hidden iframe) and then trying to authorize but that didn't work. But hopefully the above method will. It's too bad Box does not provide method to exchange between SAML for OAuth tokens like Salesforce does as that would greatly increase flexibility and possibilities for developers. I appreciate your help!

Comment: I'm glad it looks promising! Be advised that you may need to make subtle changes to the `TargetResource` URL depending on how you have your Box app configured. Check out the linked documentation for details.

Comment: May I know where or how can I get the PartnerIdpId?.