# BOX API - Is it possible to authorize user on background?

Tags: box-api, box, boxapiv2

I want to use Box on my web application using Box Embed.

But to get to specific folder, I have to use BOX API to get folder information and build my box embed programatically.

With Box API, I need to authenticate user before I can make API calls, I am done with this part, but is there a way to get token without showing the user the login form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you must be granted an access token through the [standard OAuth2 workflow](https://box-content.readme.io/#oauth-2) prior to accessing a user's Box via the API.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I saw your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22719267/1650716 ..Is it posible to use single sign on to make my user logged in, so that when they view the embed widget, they can upload files or they view it as logged in user?

Comment: You will still need to go through the OAuth2 workflow. However, since the user has already signed in (via the embed widget) they will not have to re-enter their credentials when authorizing your application. They should be taken directly to the approve/deny page.

Comment: Yes, I did get the token through OAuth2 workflow, and to construct my widget iframe, i get the folder's shared_link with API call. But when I present the embed iframe, it is viewed as "not logged in" user. Do I have it in right approach?