# Use Single sign on with Box.com using company credential and ADFS 2.0 as Idp

Tags: c#, .net, single-sign-on, adfs2.0, box

I want to create an c#.net application that allows users who have logged in to company domain by their username/password can interact with Box.net without authentication (SSO). The app flows as the following image

- Users login by their username/password to company network and call the application
- Application sends requests to Box.net, then box asks ADFS 2.0 for authentication
- Application provides ADFS the user credential, and then ADFS sends authentication result back to Box.net
- Box returns token to application and application use the token to do other actions such as uploading file, deleting files.

[app flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMluE.png)

My question is:
- How can I request Box.net for single sign on from my application 
As I have followed this instruction but it does not work
[Use SAML Single Sign-On to obtain OAuth access token or code for using Box.com API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22717764/use-saml-single-sign-on-to-obtain-oauth-access-token-or-code-for-using-box-com-a)

- After obtaining the token from Box.net, how can I do actions to Box.net as uploading, deleting...

I do not see instructions on Box.net for single sign on integrations.
please give me your ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The clue is in the title - "SSO to obtain OAuth".

ADFS 2.0 does not support OAuth.

You need to do this via SAML - refer [Single Sign On (SSO) with Box: For Administra​tors](https://community.box.com/t5/For-Admins/Single-Sign-On-SSO-with-Box-For-Administrators/ta-p/1263).